# polar hist2d not showing full circle for plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to make a polar hist2d plot, but I don't have any data on one side of the plot. However, I would still like the plot to be the full circle. Instead, it fills in white for much of the plot where there is no data.

Here is the simplest example to show what I'm talking about: make a plot with 2 points, one at 2pi/3 and one at 4pi/3 (both at radius 1),and then do a hist2d plot. It only displays the left third of the circle:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.hist2d([2*np.pi/3,4*np.pi/3],[1,1])
```

This first picture is what I'm getting, the second picture is more like what I want:
[image: This is what it's giving me now:]

[image: This is what I want it to give me:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with hist2d, but you are only graphing the circle from 2pi/3 to 4pi/3, you are first going to want to graph the who circle from 0 to 2pi radians, then proceed to plot the points for 2pi/3 and 4pi/3 onto the fully graphed circle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. How do I make it plot the whole circle first?

Comment: For example, if I add ax.set_thetamin(0) and ax.set_thetamax(360), it makes the full circle but fills the empty parts with white.

Comment: Do you think you could add a rough sketch of you want your output to be, and are you using hist2d through mathplotlib?

Comment: Done! And yes, I am.

Comment: Ok thanks, so when you initialize the subplot, use the Kwargs parameter to set “fc=‘purple’” which should color the graph purple which should fill in all the white space around your polar histogram. For some more info on the kwargs parameter check out this link: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot